# How to get the audioread.m file again in the matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio

I have edited the audioread.m file

I have used

```
which('audioread', '-all')
rmpath(fileparts(which('audioread')))
savepath
```

Now I have got an error

> Undefined function or variable 'audioread'.

I have checked with

```
[d,sr] = audioread('sadness22.wav');
% Plot the spectrogram
subplot(311)
specgram(d(:,1),1024,sr);
% Read in a different format
[d2,sr] = audioread('piano.mp3');
subplot(312)
specgram(d2(:,1),1024,sr);
```

Can you please give any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to `addpath()` the folder back, or that you want to restore the factory version of `audioread.m`?

Comment: This likely will not apply to your MATLAB installation, but just in case, the MD5 hash of `toolbox/matlab/audiovideo/audioread.m` on my system (R2019a for Linux x64) is `7f4db1c40a045b9f6571b2a694c95bdd`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox I have checked this path there is no audiovideo folder

Comment: Your question begins with, "I have edited the `audioread.m` file ..." Where was the file located at the time you edited it?

Comment: I am not sure about it. I didnt check it before. I want audioread.m file. Then i can use it anywhere else.

Comment: If `toolbox/matlab/audiovideo` does not exist on disk (and this is not `rmpath()`'s fault, since that function only affects the _search path_), I'm afraid you may have to contact the MathWorks support team, or copy the folder over from a fresh installation. Octave might have something useful, but I haven't checked it.